# How to set auto complete or auto suggestion in text field in sap ui5 like sap.m.Input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

```
this code is written in my controller.
var textField = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
    editable: true,
    liveChange:this._suggest.bind(this)
    }).bindProperty("value", name);
    _suggest:function(oevent){//this method is called for auto sugggest
    oEvent.getSource().bindAggregation("suggestionItems", path,
    new sap.ui.core.Item({
            text: "{name}"
    }));
}
```

it show a error as suggestionItems not found .

Comment: Why not [`Input - Suggestions`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputSuggestionsCustomFilter/preview)

Comment: Because i want to use ui.commons.textfield as m size is bigger than the reqirement...so please so some suggestion ..

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to execute your code..Provide a JSBin if possible..

Comment: http://jsbin.com/wopokoxawa/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Have you included `livechange` handler ?

Comment: yes but wat to write in liveChange i m not gettting anything.

Comment: I would suggest you to use input suggest and use style to deal with width..

Comment: sap.ui.commons.autocomplete works same as textfiled and suggestion also u can do ...thanks for your respose...

Comment: Is it sorted ? I am also new to this SAP UI5 world...

Comment: ya i found the solution but thanks a lot...

Comment: Regarding the default 'bigger' size of the `sap.m` controls, you can set it to a smaller size too: `this.getView().addStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact")`. I would stay clear from the `sap.commons` libraries as much as possible, since they won't be maintained anymore as far as I have heard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var oFiled = new sap.ui.commons.AutoComplete({
    editable: true,
    suggest: this._autoSuggest.bind(this)
}).bindValue("name");

_autoSuggest: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < aData.length; i++) {
        if (jQuery.sap.startsWithIgnoreCase(aData[i].name, sValue)) {
            oEvent.getSource().addItem(new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
                text: aData[i].name
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i made showSuggestion="true" and suggestionItems aggregation bind the model. It worked.